# Can I just copy paste the plugin folder in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I have to copy Eclipse across a variety of computers and every time I have to install the plugins from the update site.

Is it possible to sync my plugins folders with all the computers so that I have the same plugins across all computers?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is a lot more configuration data than just the files in the plugins/ folder.  I work on [Yoxos](https://yoxos.eclipsesource.com/) a service to help you share configurations between multiple computers.  You can also use the export your current Eclipse configuration (File -> export) and import it into another computer.

Comment: File -> export -> then what?

Comment: File -> export -> Install -> Installed Software Items to File. This will create a file of your configuration.  Then you can File -> Import -> Install to import the configuration into another Eclipse install.